# When a process makes a system call to transmit a TCP packet over the network, which of the following steps do NOT occur always?

Tags: networking, architecture, operating-system, system

I am teaching myself OS by going through the lecture notes of the course at IIT Bombay (https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~mythili/os/). One of the questions in the Process worksheet asks which of the following doesn't always happen in the situation described at the title.  **The answer is C.**

A. The process moves to kernel mode.

B. The program counter of the CPU shifts to the kernel part of the address space.

C. The process is context-switched out and a separate kernel process starts execution.

D. The OS code that deals with handling TCP/IP packets is invoked

I'm a bit confused though. I thought when an interrupt routine occurs the process is context-switched out so other processes can run and the CPU is not idle during that time. The kernel, then, will take care of the packet sending. **Why would C not be correct then?**

Comment: (C) assumes there is even such a thing as a separate kernel process. In Unix and friends there isn't, there is only the same process executing in kernel mode, as in (A). But unless the question is Unix-only that means that (A) doesn't always occur too. I don't think much of these questions.

Comment: Previous comment hits why C cannot always occur: The kernel mode process part.

Comment: I haven't watched the videos but I don't find anything in either the references or the slides for the Part A: Processes module that answers this question, or would enable you to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in saying that "when an interrupt routine occurs the process is context-switched out so other processes can run and the CPU is not idle during that time", but the words "generally or mostly" need to be added to it.

In most cases, there is another process waiting for CPU time and that can be scheduled. However it is not the case 100% of the time. The question is about the word "always" and while other options always occur in the given situation, option C is a choice that OS makes at run time. If OS determines that switching out this process can be sub optimal than performing the system call and resuming the same process, then it may not perform the context switching.

There is a cost associated with context switching and if other processes are also blocked on some I/O then it may be optimal for OS to NOT switch the context or there might be other reasons to not switch the context such as what if only 1 process is running, there is no other process to switch the context to!